# If $p\mid b$ and $q\nmid b$, then $pq\nmid b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

So I gotta prove that if $p\mid b$ and $q\nmid b$, then $pq\nmid b$, where $p,q$ are primes and $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ . The thing it seems really simple, but I coudn't do it.

So I have $p\mid b$, ie, $b=kp$. And $q\nmid b$, ie, $b=qs+r$. Which gives me $kp=qs+r$. And then, I got nothing.

Thought about isolating $q$ on the last equation, but got anywhere too.

Can someone give me a hint/direction?

Comment: *Hint :* Prove by contraposition that $q \not\mid b \Longrightarrow pq \not\mid b$, and conclude.

Comment: They do not need to be prime.  If $pq|b$ then ...?

Comment: $pq\mid b\Rightarrow q\mid b$ by *transitivity* of "divides". This is a dupe so please delete the question once all is clear.

Comment: Primes have nothing to do with it and $p$ can be any integer in the universe.  If $q\not \mid b$ then $pq\not \mid b$ no matter what $p$ is.  Why?  Because if $pq\mid b$ then *both* $q\mid b$ and $p\mid b$ but you were told *explicitely*that $q$ *doesn't* divide $b$.  So no multiple of $q$ can divide $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We’ll use proof by contradiction. 
 Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $pq|b$. Then, $\exists$  some integer m such that $$b=mpq$$ This can be recast as $$b=(mp)q=aq$$ whre a is another integer. But $b=aq$ implies that $q|b$, which contradicts the hypothesis. Hence our assumption that $pq|b$ is false. Hence proved.

**NOTE** that $p|b$ is irrelevant here because we haven’t used it at all in our argument. Thus, the conclusion is that $pq|b \implies p|b$ as well as $q|b$.